# icons are not in the footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I would like to create footer in the bottom of my webpage with social icons in.
I tried this :

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #111111;
}

#footer .social {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer .social ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#footer .social li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#footer .social li:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li><img  src="./images/footer/twitter.png" /></li>
                <li><img  src="./images/footer/email.png" /><li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But the result is like :

[image: result]

Thanks for reading

Comment: Could you put them into a jsFiddle so we can play with them? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Different browsers set different default CSS rules in there browsers known as user agent stylesheet.**

Here for `ul` there may be a default `margin`, You should reset it to `0`;

Here in your code, Try Adding:

```
#footer .social ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

Or you can reset the whole user agent styles by including a **reset.css** or a **normalise.css** (Google any of these and find).

Answer (score 0):

Use these code for the footer id. I think you are asking for this, if not let me know:

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
height: 60px;
background: #111111;
}
```

You can add the `#footer .social ul {margin:0;}` also as @Prasanth K C said.